# How to dynamically change id based on page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple page with 3 big sections (Blue, red and gray) and fix positioned move up & down arrow. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/81yy0a0z/)

Currently when I click the DOWN arrow it drag/scroll to the Bottom Gray section and When I click on the UP arrow it takes to the Top Blue Section. So far this is good. But I was thinking to make it more dynamic.

Is this possible to make:
If I click on the **DOWN/UP** arrow it will only Scroll to NEXT **bottom/Upper** Section.

**scenario 1:** I am on the Blue Section clicking DOWN arrow will move to Red section and again clicking on the DOWN arrow will scroll to the Gray Section

**scenario 2:** If I mouse scroll to red section and click the DOWN arrow it will Scroll me to Gray Section

Same for UP arrow.

Main idea is to scroll to next section based on current position when I click any UP or DOWN arrow.

I am really a complete beginner to write any jQuery/javaScripts for this.I'm not even sure if this is possible with jQuery.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='div1' id='position1'></div>
    <div class='div2' id='position2'></div>
    <div class='div3' id='position3'></div>

    <div class='move-down'><a href='#position3'>v</a></div>
    <div class='move-up'><a href='#position1'>^</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar lately, but with mousewheel, should be no problem to adapt it to your button needs.

[Here is a fiddle to show with scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/81yy0a0z/1/)

And here is the code:

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

    function transitionTo(elem){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top

        }, 2000, function ()  {
            flag = true;
            flag1 = true;
            flag2 = true;
        });
    }

    function getDelta(e){
        var evt = window.event || e ;
        evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
        return evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;
    }

    var flag = true;
    $('#position1').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = getDelta(e);

        if(delta < 0 && flag == true)
        {
            flag = false;
            transitionTo('#position2');
        }

    });

    var flag1 = true;
    $('#position2').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = getDelta(e);

        if(delta < 0 && flag1 == true)
        {
            flag1 = false;
            transitionTo('#position3');
        }
        else if (delta > 0 && flag1 == true) {
            flag1 = false;
            transitionTo('#position1');
        }
    });

    var flag2 = true;
    $('#position3').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = getDelta(e);

        if(delta < 0)
        {


        }
        else if (delta > 0 && flag2 == true) {
            flag2 = false;
            transitionTo('#position2');
        }
    });
```

To let your buttons interact with the same transition, add this below:

```
$('#position1').on('mouseover', function () {
    var position = 1;
    $('.move-down').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            transitionTo('#position2');
        });
});
$('#position2').on('mouseover',function () {
    var position = 2;
    $('.move-down').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            transitionTo('#position3');
        });
    $('.move-up').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            transitionTo('#position1');
        });
});
$('#position3').on('mouseover',function () {
     var position = 3;

    $('.move-up').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            transitionTo('#position2');
        });
});
```

---

Simply find the current div and rewrite the functions at the bottom accordingly...

Comment: If you can show me how I can relate mousewheel with my button click  that would help me so much ! I am not good to find any relations between them  :)

Comment: It does only work when you exit the button for a second and go into it again after, but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/81yy0a0z/3/